# How do I display a message to users, with the selections they has made from the contextual filter?

Tags: views

I have a view with more than one contextual filters.
For example, filter on Age, and Gender. if the filter is on Age, and/or gender
I would like to display a message to the user regarding the selections he/she has made. i.e, Message to user: "you are filtering on age"...
How can i achieve this? I thought about writing my own module to do it, but i figured there might be an exiting module, or solution that does this already.

Thank!!

Answer (score 2):

You can add a Header to the view, some of the tokens you can add include the Contextual filter values